# ggplot2 image not showing up in pdf from Rmd

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown, pandoc

Sort of new to R markdown. I define a function that makes a plot with ggplot2 in a separate .R file:

```
heatMapDevRatio <- function(glmnet_obj_list,alpha_seq,
                        plot_name){
grid <- matrix(NA,nr=1,ncol=3)    
colnames(grid) = c('alpha','lambda','dev.ratio')
for(idx in 1:length(glmnet_obj_list)){
    alpha = getAlpha(names(glmnet_obj_list)[idx])
    temp_df = data.frame(alpha=alpha,
                         lambda=glmnet_obj_list[[idx]]$lambda,
                         dev.ratio=glmnet_obj_list[[idx]]$dev.ratio)
    grid = rbind(grid,temp_df)
}
grid = grid[-1,]

ggplot(data = grid, aes(lambda, alpha)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = dev.ratio), interpolate = TRUE) +
    ggtitle(plot_name) +
    xlab(expression(~lambda)) +
    ylab(expression(~alpha))
```

}

Anyway, the function runs fine-- the output goes to the standard graphics device if I run it in interactive session, or wherever I direct it if use the function in a script.

The problem is when I run the function in an Rmd file after source()-ing the file with the function definition.

````
```{r heatmap     10yr,eval=T,echo=F,fig.height=4,fig.width=4,fig.cap='lkjafkd'}
 heatMapDevRatio(fitted_mods_20yr[2:10],alpha_seq,'adfasfd')
 ```
````

The export to pdf works, but on the pdf I just have a reference to some weird directory that doesn't seem to exist after execution-- where the figure should be, I have this text:

```
![lkjafkd](cox_summary[exported]_files/figure-latex/heatmap 10yr-1.pdf)
```

Should I just write the image to a file and include it, or should I be redirecting the graphics output? I thought it should just work.

Do you think the problem is the command I'm using to weave?

```
     Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('cox_summary.Rmd', output_format = 'pdf_document', output_file = 'cox_summary[exported].pdf')"
```

Comment: Might not be the problem, but I would avoid spaces in my chunk names.

Comment: Can you give us some example data to work with or use `dput`?

Comment: Did you try without the spaces in the chunk name?

Comment: yea, the spaces in the chunk name aren't responsible.